# My bathymetric sounder only exports to XYZ file want to input into GRASS

Tags: xyz, bathymetry, input

The export file has long, lat, elevation in a float format i.e. -70.8838319778442, 42.3222159164251, -14.6

The file is over 18 MB and each lat/long/elev is MOSTLY 1.5 meter apart and sometime maybe up to 5 meters.
I am brand new to GIS, like 8 hours old, how to input data into a GIS (Open Source only) and keeping the lat/long info to overlay perfectly on a nautical chart?

Answer (score 2):

Download QGIS 3.14. It is open source and easy to use. Then in the main menu select

Layer -> Add Layer -> Add Delimited Text Layer

This menu pops up - for geometry loading it is crucial to set which fields are coordinates and what their coordinate reference system is.
[image]

After configuring layer options just load and this is the effect
[image]

You can then easily overlay it on some basemap.
[image]

Comment: For a nautical chart base layer, try `Layer/Add layer/Add WMS/WMTS Layer` Then a `New` connection to `https://seamlessrnc.nauticalcharts.noaa.gov/arcgis/services/RNC/NOAA_RNC/ImageServer/WMSServer?request=GetCapabilities&service=WMS` for the RNC charts from NOAA, then `Connect` to it, choose a `NOAA_RNC` layer and then `Add`.  This is from the "Seamless Raster Nautical Chart service from https://nauticalcharts.noaa.gov/data/gis-data-and-services.html#seamless-raster-nautical-chart-services